# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF or Xacro?

Tags: microcontroller, urdf, xacro, plugin, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I have been using SolidWorks Exporter for generating URDF for my robot.
Things didn't go well adding transmissions and controller plugins, Gazebo crashes if I spawn the urdf with controller plugins and transmissions, so I started studying other robots in ROS in detail (for example universal-robot) and all of them had Xacro files.
Should I also use Xacro? Or the URDF generated by SolidWorks should work fine with transmissions and controller plugins?
If I should use xacro, how do I generate a Xacro?

Thanks for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202162/urdf-or-xacro?/) by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-01-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Xacro is just a scripting mechanism that allows more modularity and code re-use when defining a URDF model. When using it, what is actually uploaded to the parameter servers (per default as the "robot_description" parameter) actually is a URDF, as that gets generated from the xacro file in the launch file (by expanding the xacro macros used).

As an example, say you have a "robot.urdf.xacro" file. You can run

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py robot.urdf.xacro > robot.urdf
```

and that gives you the URDF generated from your xacro file. The same approach is commonly used in launch files when a xacro-based robot_description is uploaded.

Xacro is just another way of defining a URDF, not an alternative to it. It makes certain things easier, for instance you can generate a "wheel" macro and instantiate that 6 times with different parameters to put 6 wheels on your robot, as opposed to copying and pasting the same code six times manually.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) on 2015-01-31**:
Thanks, then I will stick to my SolidWorks Exporter generated URDF.

**Comment by [Yanhao Zhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/44934/yanhao-zhu/) on 2019-08-17**:
Also new to urdf and have a similar confusion. Really a good answer!